# Calculate Projectile impact with a moving Target

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, gravity, kinematics, projectile

I'm trying to solve the classic shoot moving object issue in 3D Space, but with acceleration and gravity added to it.

I already tried several ways approaching the correct calculation, yet I face the same problem with each and I'll show you which one, maybe someone is able to help me out here.

**Example:**

So let's assume there is a flying rocket which I want to hit using a sniper rifle.
For this I have the information below.

**Known Information:**

- `s` the speed of the sniper bullet (150 M/s)
- `pT` the position of the Rocket / Target as Vector 3 (0, 100, 0)
- `pV` the velocity of the Rocket / Target as Vector 3 (50, 0, 0)
- `pA` the acceleration of the Rocket / Target as Vector 3 (5, 0, 0)
- `lT` the position of the Sniper rifle as Vector 3 (100, 0, 100)
- `g` the gravity force which pulls the Bullet down but ignores the Rocket / Target (9.81 M/s)

**Unknown Information (What I want to calculate):**

- `lV` the launch velocity of the Bullet to hit the Rocket / Target (where I have to aim to hit)
- `t` the travel time the bullet needs to hit the Rocket / Target

**How it looks like (Not completely accurate):**
[image]

**My first Approach:**

So to calculate where I have to shoot, I need the travel time first, since I need to know where the Target will be if I would shoot now.

My first attempt to calculate the travel time was with the help of a quartic function which looks like this:

- a = acceleration
- v = target velocity
- p = rocket position - sniper position
- s = bullet speed

$$ \begin{align}
0 &= t^4 \left(\frac 1 4 \vec a \cdot \vec a \right)\\
  &+ t^3 \left(\vec a \cdot \vec v \right)\\
  &+ t^2 \left(\vec a \cdot \vec p + \vec v \cdot \vec v - s^2 \right)\\
  &+ t^1 \left(2\vec p \cdot \vec v \right)\\
  &+ 1 \left( \vec p \cdot \vec p\right)\\
\end{align}$$

This returns the correct time without the impact of Gravity or any downward force, assuming the Bullet travels in a straight path which basically looks like this:
[image]

But since in my Example, the Bullet is affected by Gravity, it won't travel in a straight line but in a curve, so the time will be different. What I want to calculate is the travel time for a Bullet that flies like this:
[image]

**My second Approach:**

I have read that I can use the "range equation" to get the time but there is the following problem.

To get the time with the Range Equation I need to calculate the launch angle first, the formular looks like this:

- g = gravity
- d = distance
- v = target velocity

$$ \begin{align}
0 &= \frac {sin^{-1}(g \cdot \frac d {v^2})} 2
\end{align}$$

**The Problem:**

And here is the problem. To calculate the launch angle, you need the distance to the target.

If I would take the current distance to the target, then I would get back the time in seconds, which the bullet needs to hit the rocket at the current rocket position which wont help me cuz the Target won't be at that position anymore once I shoot.

But I want to calculate the time the Bullet needs to hit the rocket, not the time the Bullet needs to get to a position where the rocket will not be then.

That means, to get the travel time to impact, I would need to know the position of the rocket at impact, and to know the position of the rocket at impact, I would need the travel time....

I am therefore in a quandary and don't know what to do.

Maybe someone has an Idea on this dilemma?

Comment: Develop an equation for bullet position vs. time.  Develop another equation for rocket position vs. time.  Set the two equations equal to each other and solve for time.